# Data splitting in DolphinDB

Tags: list, data-processing, dolphindb

I want to split a vector into n parts in DolphinDB. Any easier way to do this?

In Python, I can do this with the following script:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
newarr = np.array_split(arr, 3)
print(newarr)

# output
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])]
```

Is there any function like `array_split` in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cut` function to split the array. Its parameter size is used to specify the size of each vector output, so you need to calculate the size of each part. The script is as follows.

```
v.cut(ceil(v.size()\N))
```